# Finding a limit for a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I have this complex limit which is rather difficult to solve.

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\longrightarrow3i}\frac{z^2+9}{z-3i}
\end{equation}

clearly, it I insert $3i$ for $z$, I get $\frac{0}{0}$, so that won't work. I multiply with the complex conjugate, and get

\begin{equation}
\frac{z^2+9}{z-3i}\frac{z+3i}{z+3i}=\frac{z(z^2+3i+9)+27i}{z^2+9}
\end{equation}

But here I still get the form $\frac{0}{0}$ when I insert for $3i$. What is the right thing to do here?

Thanks

Comment: Like you mentioned, we get $\frac{z^2+9}{z-3i}\cdot\frac{z+3i}{z+3i}=\frac{(z^2+9)(z+3i)}{z^2+9}=z+3i$ for all $z\neq \pm 3i$.

Comment: Thanks, I see this clearly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your limit has a look $\bbox[lightgreen]{\lim\frac{0}{0}}$, therefore, you can use the **L'Hopital's rule**:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\longrightarrow{3i}}\frac{(z^2+9)'}{(z-3i)^{'}}=\lim_{z\longrightarrow{3i}}(2z)=6i.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks, this was even more practical.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $z^2+9=z^2-9i^2=(z+3i)(z-3i)$.